# LB Conduit to interior wall 90 degree bend

Tags: electrical, subpanel, conduit, detached-structure

I'm running 1 1/4" PVC conduit underground from my home's main panel over to a subpanel in an accessory structure. I'd like to have the conduit enter the structure low to the ground so it's not so visible.  The part I'm a little stuck on is how to go from entering the structure horizontally (via an LB) to straight up 90 degrees into the subpanel (~4ft off the floor).

Some suggestions I've seen (and why I haven't went with them yet):

1. **Just run the conduit high enough to enter the panel directly from the back**

   I'd prefer to keep it lower if possible, and it may be a little tricker to align the knockout correctly, but this is my plan if nothing else
2. **Add a *junction box/LB/pull elbow* inside as well, which has to be exposed in the wall**

   I don't hate this option, but I also would prefer not to add anything else visible on the finished interior
3. **Transition to 1" ENT after the LB, and make a tight bend (plus it makes it easier to line up the knockout in the subpanel)**

   It doesn't seem like 1" ENT will bend that much to fit in the 3.5" wall space, if it does, I'm not sure if it will pass inspection. I'd love to be wrong about both of these things.
4. **Move the conduit to go up under the floor and straight into wall**

   I don't think the steel frame will allow it
5. **Move the conduit to enter the other side of the corner of the building, so a standard radius 90 to turn upwards will fit**

   Might have been a good option originally, but with it already buried how it is, I think I'd go with option 1 over the extra work this would involve

Are there other up-to-code options I haven't considered, which allow me to have a low height entrance that goes directly to the panel?

Thanks in advance!

[image: exterior view]

Comment: What kind of wire are you running that you need 1-1/4" conduit? You might want/need to go from the LB directly into a large junction box and transition to a different type of wire to make the bend. Option #4 would be my suggestion - it may be worth investigating further.

Comment: 3 #6 and 1 #10 THWN

Comment: AL or CU? How much amperage, how long a run? _Have you already purchased the wire?_ I'm probably not going to have the answers for you, but supplying as much detail as possible will help those who do have the knowledge give you the best answer.

Comment: Copper, 50 amps, I have the wire already (100’ each, total run is about 80’)

Comment: Why are you using 1¼"? How did you calculate that?  What is the single #10 wire for?  If you could use 1" or use a reducing bushing on the LB, you could go into the back of an 11B junction box.  With that, you can get a single gang mud ring, trim out an outlet right below the panel to "hide" your pull box.  Edit: Looks like they actually make 11B with 1¼" KOs.

Comment: @Andrew -- the #10 is the EGC (#10 EGCs are good up to 60A as per NEC Table 250.122)

Comment: +1 to ThreePhaseEel - I could have used 1" (or possible 3/4"?, I forget), but 1 ¼" should make pulling the wire easier and keep space for future expansion.

Comment: But, I ultimately did something similar to Andrew's suggestion.  The LB will enter the building a foot or so above the ground, and go to a single gang box mounted so that it is accessible from the interior.  The box has a 1" exit built in to the top(a 1 1/4" wasn't available), and I plan to drill a hole to attach the LB into a box adapter. From there, a 1¼" reducer  and 1¼" up to the panel. 
If its too tight, i got a 4" square junction box to use instead.